# WP_Query order by custom meta value and then order by modified

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to order a `wp_query` that includes a `meta_query`...
After some different approaches, it seems that the query can't be ordered since I include the `meta_query`, and `orderby => ID` is used by default (I think) and it can't be overwritten. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?
Here's the PHP code I use just to display the posts by meta value:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : (get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'subtitrare',
            'value' => 'romana',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$listing_query = null;
$listing_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($listing_query->have_posts()) : get_template_part('loop-item');
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

As you can see I also paginate the results, so i can use the same `$args`. I've tried to use a custom function to rearrange the results but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: What do you want it ordered by?

Comment: tried orderby -> modified with no succes. so i wanna sort it by modified date DESC

Comment: I'm gonna rephrase it a little bit. I wanna rearrange the results again, after their post_modified in wp_post. So they are first arranged by meta_value using the default meta_id and the result rearrange by the post_modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'subtitrare',
            'value' => 'romana',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

This is the code you need but you already said that you tried this. This will return all the posts which have the custom field value set to LIKE 'romana'. What are the results you get from using this code?

Comment: That was the first this i've tried. Trust me :) ... the problem is that the query ignored this orderby because of the meta_query ... by default the meta_query is arranged by meta_id (i think) so id doesn't matter if you place another 'orderby' in the query ... this needs another approach like "storing" or whatever the first query and rearrange it again after the post_modified. Obviously your suggestion didn't worked, and although i tried it in the first time, i made sure by trying again now and still no change.